# Does using a self-signed certificate for signing apps influence which Android devices can see the app in the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

this is a more tightly focused version of the same problem which I've asked about here: [App on Play Store invisible to Android 11 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011208/app-on-play-store-invisible-to-android-11-devices)

In that previous question, I only briefly wondered about signing. Here, I'm deliberately focusing on signing.

In March 2021, the Play Store started asking that I comply with the new v2 signing method whereby the developer must sign an APK before uploading it to the store. I successfully moved over to that method, the APKs are accepted by the Play Store. When I do it wrong, the Play Store rejects the APK immediately on the upload completing.

At some point (and it's hard to say if these things are truly related) I got feedback from people running devices on Android 11 saying they can't see my app in the store at all. Devices < Android 11 continue to see updates that I upload for my app.

I've done a ton of troubleshooting of the AndroidManifest.xml file. See the other question that I linked to higher up. I don't think that's the problem.

**I am left with wondering about the signing aspect of the situation. All I can tell you about my certificate is that it's self-signed. Is this a problem for either the Play Store or Android 11 devices?**

Thanks for any help.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

No, the certificate you use has no incidence on the visibility of your app in the Play Store or Android in general.

When you say people can't find your app, is it that they can't find it by searching some keywords, or they can't access the Play store listing using a deep link?

There is no real guidance on how to make your app findable on the store using search, it will largely depend on the popularity of your app, the quality of your app, and the competition on the search words with other apps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 

When I send a deep link to people with Android 11 devices, they can install the app. It also runs fine. That's OK.

My app is "I Grow Chicken". If I type that into the search bar in the Play Store on an Android 9 or 10 device, it's the top hit. If I type that into the search bar in the Play Store on an Android 11 device, it's nowhere to be seen. It's not in the top 10. Now to be honest, it's not got a great score (blush). I understand that it would appear low in the results if i searched for "poultry" but it's just strange that typing the actual name = nada.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue. I managed to download the APK on an older device, and it looks like it has a maxSdkVersion=29 set in the manifest. So that would explain why a device with Android 11 would not be eligible to install it, and thus why the Play Store is not showing it in the search results.

Comment: Pierre, you're a star but that's our app on Production.

I have been putting updates out on the internal track with maxSdkVersion cleared or even set to 30.

Oh, wait ... are you saying that until I publish an app version to PRODUCTION with the maxSdkVersion set to 30 (or completely unset) ... I won't *ever* see the APK on Android 11?

Heh. I've messed so much with with the SDK version levels but didn't think to publish a new APK to production.

Do you think I should unset the maxSdkVersion completely or that I should set it to a value?

Thanks for the help so far!!!!

Comment: I don't think you should set the maxSdkVersion at all. Android is designed to be backwards compatible and all behaviour changes are controlled by the targetSdkVersion. In practice, some big changes are still forced even with a new version of Android, but that's why there is a long beta phase, so that app developers have time to test their app with the new version of Android and ensure it works well when it eventually is released for everyone.

Comment: your answer here is in fact the correct answer for the same question I logged with a different formulation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011208/app-on-play-store-invisible-to-android-11-devices

If you want the karma on that question, go ahead and copy-paste your answer to that question and I'll mark it as the answer.